# How to nest container class in simple project with SASS?

Tags: sass

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="container"></div>
</section>
<nav>
  <div class="container"></div>
</nav>
```

How to nest container class?
Probably not like this:

```
section {
  .container {
  }
}

nav {
 .continer {
 }
}
```

Because I don't want to double style for .container.
And not like this:

```
.container {
  section {
  }
  nav {
  }
}
```

Because container is in section, not section in container. So how?

I can use " & " but:

```
body {
  .container {
     section & {
     }
  }
}
```

will compile to:

```
 section body .container {
 }
```

but i need:

```
body section .container {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it by using the '&' which references the parent selector.

```
.container {
  section & {
    color: blue;
  }

  nav & {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

The above will compile to

```
section .container {
  color: blue;
}

nav .container {
  color: black;
}
```

The way you mentioned above would compile the other way around like:

```
.container section {
}
```

which is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, but when I style body one line higher i will get:
   section body .container {}
in css.

Comment: Where and how did you put it?

Comment: Look on my question again, please. I explained.

Comment: Well, if you follow the answer, you would just need to add body within the nested portion. body section & || body nav &

Answer (score 0):

To add styles to the container div that will display within both section and nav:

```
section, nav {
  .container {
      color: red;
  }
}
```

which compiles to

```
section .container {color: red;}
nav .container {color: red;}
```